# composer update cannot resolve dependencies

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

My composer.json file is:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "<=3.0.12",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",

        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.5.*@dev",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.4.*@dev",

        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0-beta1",

        "twbs/bootstrap": "~3.3.0",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.3.*@dev",

        "bmatzner/fontawesome-bundle": "~4.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-extensions": "~1.0",
        "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.4.*",
        "friendsofsymfony/message-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^1.7",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1",
        "voryx/restgeneratorbundle": "0.3",
        "javiereguiluz/easyadmin-bundle": "^1.16",
        "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "^1.0"


    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.7-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run

```
composer update
```

I get this error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle 2.4.3 exists as knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle[2.3.3, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.5.4, dev-fix/tests, dev-master, 2.8.x-dev, v2.0, v2.1, v2.2, v2.3, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.6.0, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.8.0] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package knplabs/knp-menu-bundle 2.4.3 exists as knplabs/knp-menu-bundle[1.1.x-dev, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, dev-master, 2.2.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.1.0, v1.1.1, v1.1.2, v2.0.0, v2.0.0-alpha1, v2.0.0-alpha2, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.2.0, v2.2.1] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 3
    - The requested package knplabs/knp-menu 2.4.3 exists as knplabs/knp-menu[1.1.x-dev, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, dev-breadcrumb_renderer, dev-master, 2.4.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.1.0, v1.1.1, v1.1.2, v2.0.0, v2.0.0-alpha1, v2.0.0-alpha2, v2.0.0-beta1, v2.0.1, v2.1.0, v2.1.1] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.49
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.48
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.47
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.46
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.45
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.44
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.43
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.42
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.41
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.40
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.39
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.38
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.37
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.36
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.35
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.34
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.33
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.32
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.31
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.30
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.29
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.28
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.27
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.26
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.25
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.24
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.23
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.22
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.21
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.20
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.19
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.18
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.17
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.16
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.15
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.14
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.13
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.12
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.11
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.10
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.3
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/message-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/message-bundle[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.1
    - friendsofsymfony/message-bundle dev-master requires symfony/twig-bundle ^2.8.45|^3.0|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/twig-bundle[v2.8.45, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.16, v3.3.17, v3.3.18, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.2, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.11, v4.0.12, v4.0.13, v4.0.14, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4].
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v2.8.45|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.0.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.0.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.0.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.0.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.0.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.0.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.0.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.0.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.0.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.2.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.2.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.2.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.2.13|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.2.14|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.2.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.2.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.2.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.2.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/twig-bundle v3.2.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.10 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.11 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.12 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.13 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.14 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.15 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.16 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.17 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.18 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.4 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.5 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.6 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.7 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.8 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.3.9 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.4.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.4.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.4.10 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.4.11 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.4.12 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.4.13 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.4.14 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.4.15 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.4.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.4.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.4.4 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.4.5 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.4.6 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.4.7 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.4.8 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v3.4.9 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.0.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.0.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.0.10 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.0.11 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.0.12 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.0.13 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.0.14 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.0.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.0.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.0.4 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.0.5 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.0.6 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.0.7 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.0.8 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.0.9 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.1.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.1.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.1.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.1.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - symfony/twig-bundle v4.1.4 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.7.0].
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.7.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.4, v2.7.40, v2.7.41, v2.7.42, v2.7.43, v2.7.44, v2.7.45, v2.7.46, v2.7.47, v2.7.48, v2.7.49, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9].
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Wow.  Talk about a blast from the past.  What php version are you using?  Guessing it is pretty recent.

Comment: @Cerad Why do you think it's a recent version? It's for a work project and I don't have much control over it.

Comment: @Cerad I am on php 7.1.15

Comment: For starters, 2.7 will not even run on php 7+ due to some php bc changes.  I think 2.8 will but not sure.  There is a way to tell composer which version of php to use when determining dependencies.  I forget the syntax but you can look it up.  But even if you get everything to load, it probably will not run.  Might want to look at using a virtual machine or docker.

Comment: I'm already on docker. Are you suggesting that I try an earlier version of php?

Comment: It is worth a try.  5.6.whatever should at least load Symfony 2.7.  However, so many of your dependencies are dev master.  Who knows what you will actually end up with.  I am thinking you will need to do quite a bit of trial and error before things load smoothly.  Good luck.

Comment: I forgot to mention but if you do happen to have a working copy of the app then try grabbing the composer.lock file and using install instead of update.  Might get lucky.

Comment: Moreover, the dev-master version constrsint on the knp* packages will cause problems. Try to select a numbered version as minimum and let composer choose then